# Change record title in a StackedInline in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to either change or remove the title for each record in an inline, but have not been able to find a way to do it in the docs or by override get_formset. Specifically, I want to change or remove the title highlighted in the attached image. Any ideas how to do it please? Preferably without overriding CSS etc.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try setting a `__str__(self)` method for the AppHomePageItem class. That should be the trick